# I want to display data when i click on customer name form dropdown list it will display only that customer's message and entry date

Tags: php, mysql, yii

My code works properly, it is display all messages and entry dates. I want to display message and entry date when I select customer name from drop down list.

Here is my controller `CustomerlifecycleController`

```
    public function actionCustomerlifecycleanalytic() {                           
     $customername = Customer::model()->findall("store_id='" . Yii::app()->session['store_id'] . "'");
     $customerlifecycle = CustomerLifecycle::model()->findAll();
     $this->renderPartial('customerlifecycleanalytic', array( 'customername' => $customername, 'customerlifecycle' => $customerlifecycle), false, true);
}
```

Here is my view file `customerlifecycleanalytic.php`
Dropdown list
Customer name fetch from customer model
and there is column name `id` for customer

```
   <select class="form-control selectpicker customerfilter">
        <option value=''>Select Customer</option>

        <?php
        if (isset($customername)) {
            foreach ($customername as $customernames) {

                echo '<option value="' . $customernames['id'] . '" >' . $customernames['firstname'].'&nbsp'. $customernames['lastname']. '</option>';
            }
        }
        ?>
    </select>
```

Message and entry date fetch from `Customerlifecycle` model there is column name is `customer_id`

```
    $msg = '<li {classstr}>
                    <div class="tl-circ">
                    </div>
                    <div class="timeline-panel">

                        <div class="tl-body">
                            <p>
                               {msg} on {date}</p>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>';

    $cnt = 0;
    $htmlstring = '';
    foreach ($customerlifecycle as $key => $row) {
        $htmlstring .= $msg;
        $classString ='';
        if ($cnt % 2 == 0) {
            $classString = " class='timeline-inverted' ";
        }
        $htmlstring = str_replace("{classstr}", "$classString", $htmlstring);
        $htmlstring = str_replace("{msg}", "$row->message", $htmlstring);
        $htmlstring = str_replace("{date}", "$row->entrydate", $htmlstring);
        $cnt++;
    }


   echo $htmlstring;
    ?>
```

My code is already running completely but I want when I select customer name form drop down list at that time it will display only that customer's message and entry date.

Answer (score 0):

To display selected customer's message and entry date, you can call javascript function on onChange event of dropdownlist as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript">
        function submitForm() {
                document.getElementById("form-id").submit();
        }
</script>
<select class="form-control selectpicker customerfilter" name="Customer[id]" onChange="js: return submitForm();">
```

Using this javascript function, submit the form and make changes in your controller as follows:

```
public function actionCustomerlifecycleanalytic() {                           
     $customername = Customer::model()->findall("store_id='" . Yii::app()->session['store_id'] . "'");
         $strCondition = "";
         if(isset($_POST['Customer'])) {
                if (!empty($_POST['Customer']['id'])) {
                        $strCondition .= "store_id = '" . Yii::app()->session['store_id'] . "' AND customer_id = '" . $_POST['Customer']['id'] . "'";
                }
        }
        $customerlifecycle = CustomerLifecycle::model()->findAll($strCondition);
        $this->renderPartial('customerlifecycleanalytic', array( 'customername' => $customername, 'customerlifecycle' => $customerlifecycle), false, true);
}
```

Hope this helps!